# Google Place Photo Requests Broken?

Tags: php, google-places-api, google-places

We are attempting to use the Google Place Photo Requests

> (https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/photos#place_photo_requests)

API to fetch photos, but are constantly getting the quota exceeded image.

We have signed up for a paid account, as well as set up a brand new account, and continue to get this error.

To reproduce we:

1) First ran the Place Details request from the server **(/maps/api/place/details/json)** via PHP.

2) Then from this result set we fetched the `(['result']['photos'][0]['photo_reference'])` photoreference.

3) With the photoreference, key, sensor and maxwidth variables we called **/maps/api/place/photo** (via PHP).

We can not seem to get this to work. Has anybody else successfully used this or has any advice?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I get the same and see it mentioned a lot even 8 years later

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are either sending us a lot of requests, or you aren't adding your key to the photo fetch. Have you had any successful requests? If not, I'd suspect your keys are missing and/or incorrect.

Comment: We tried with a brand new key, and the photo requests aren't working either. Oddly, when we use the sample provided on the Google Places API documentation, even this returns the overlimit image.

We were very careful to ensure we included the API keys. Of interest, the JavaScript API returns the images fine, it's just the server-side one we can't seem to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.. It works for me

```
<h3>Images From Google </h3>
<?php

$company_name = 'walmart';
$data_ref = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=Latitude ,Longitude&radius=100&name=".$company_name."&types=store&sensor=false&key=MYKEY");


$data_ref_de = json_decode($data_ref);

if($data_ref_de->status=='OK')
{


    foreach($data_ref_de->results as $result)
    {
        if(isset($result->photos) && count($result->photos))
        {
            foreach($result->photos as $photos)
            {?>
               //Display Image

            <img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=600&photoreference=<?php echo $photos->photo_reference; ?>&sensor=true&key=MYKEY" />

            <?php 
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And also be sure that you have enabled the `Places API` Service